# .NET 5 website requires two hosting bundles?

Tags: .net, iis-10

I have a .NET 5 website. In one (just one) environment it won't run unless I have both the .NET 5 and .NET Core 2.1.15 hosting bundles installed. If I remove either hosting bundle (but leave the runtimes), I get error:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

I don't know what the error is as it does not appear in the Windows Event viewer, and nothing appears in the IIS log file.

I do note that in the IIS manager if I click on the website, and double click "Logging", that I see the following error if .NET Core 2.1.15 hosting bundle is not installed (but works as expected otherwise):

> There was an error while performing this operation.
> Details: Filename: \?\D:\www\web.config
> Error:

Comment: Activate [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-arr-using-frt-rules) in IIS. Also [enable logging in Web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/logging-and-diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-8.0): `<aspNetCore ... stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..." .../>`.

Comment: .NET 5 doesn't require two hosting bundles BUT it's already past its End Of Life. It was well known that it was a single-year version just like all odd .NET Core versions. The oldest supported Long Term Support version (3 year support) is .NET 6, supported until November 2024. The current LTS version is 8.

Comment: .NET Core 2.1 is way past its End Of Life too (August 2021). You should really, really migrate to .NET 6. This isn't an "in an ideal world" or a "can't follow Microsoft" case. The .NET Core lifecycle is known.

Comment: You only need the latest .NET server hosting bundle. But on an old machine with multiple versions of that bundle installed, you cannot easily uninstall the old, as it might break the new. BTW, .NET 5 or .NET Core 2.x are long dead, so either .NET 6 or 8 is your option to move on. People dislike talking about dead products.

Comment: @LexLi When I remove all but .NET 5 hosting environment, and re-install the hosting environment, the website won't run from IIS (but it will from command line). If I then re-install the 2.1 hosting bungle it works without error.

Comment: @UweKeim I have logging enable as per your example, it produces a 0-byte file when either of the .net 5 or .net 2.1 hosting bundle is not installed (but there are not errors if both are installed) and I try to go to the site in a browser.

Comment: "If I then re-install the 2.1 hosting bungle it works without error" seems to indicate that you are hosting a .NET Core 2.1 legacy app, so merely installing .NET 5 hosting bundle won't work because no .NET Core 2.1 runtime is there. You might try the mixture of .NET 5 hosting bundle with .NET Core 2.1 runtime (another installer, not the hosting bundle), and I believe that will work flawlessly.

Comment: @LexLi It's a .NET 5 website, it's the only website hosted by IIS on this machine. But if I remove EITHER of the .NET 5 -or- the 2.1 hosting bundle the website stops working. Removing either causes the error, when both are installed there are no issues.

Comment: Rarely people keep end of life bits on their machines, so don't expect others here can reproduce it (especially without your web app). Either you upgrade to a supported .NET release, or you can only help yourself out.

Comment: Check the application's web.config file to make sure there aren't any errors or incompatible configurations. Pay special attention to whether there is anything related to .NET Core 2.1.15 in the configuration.